# Merge rows with the same values Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe as follows:

[image]

You will note here that there are many rows with the same `code_module,code_presentation,id_student` combination
What I want to do is merge all of these duplicate rows, and in so sum the `sum_clicks` with each group

An example of this is for the top rows they would be merged into one row looking as follows:

```
         code_module code_presentation  id_student  sum_click
0                AAA             2013J       28400          18
```

In SQL terms, the private key should be a `code_module,code_presentation,id_student` combination

In my progress on this, I tried to use groupby in the following way:

```py
groupby(['id_student','code_presentation','code_module']).aggregate({'sum_click': 'sum',})
```

But this didn't work as it gave student ids that aren't even in my dataset, which I don't understand why

Also, groupby doesn't seem to be quite what I'm looking for as it has a datastructure different to a standard pandas dataframe, which is what I would be looking for.

The problem can be seen in the following output

```
                                        sum_click
id_student code_presentation code_module           
6516       2014J             AAA               2791
8462       2013J             DDD                646
          2014J             DDD                 10
11391      2013J             AAA                934
```

Row 1 and 2 (indexing from 0) should be distinct rows, instead of the group as they are

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this -

```
df.groupby(['code_module', 'code_presentation', 'id_student']).agg(sum_clicks=('sum_click', 'sum')).reset_index()
```